# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError ORA-01804 but I set environment variable already

Tags: python, oracle, apache, docker, mod-wsgi

I want connect apache and python(flask) and Oracle on Centos 7 Docker.

Apache and flask is connected by mod_wsgi and It work well.

But I connect Oracle, wsgi error occurs.

here my python code.

```
import flask
from flask import Response
from flask import request
import logging
import os
import cx_Oracle

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET',])
def index():
    return "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>" # it work well

@app.route('/select_test', methods=['GET',])
def selectDB():
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("test", "1234", "127.0.0.1:1521/XE") # error occurs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("") # no sql, because it is connect test
    cursor.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return ""
```

error log is here.

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 1116] [client 172.17.0.1:54802]   File "/opt/python_app/hello_world.py", line 17, in selectDB
[wsgi:error] [pid 1116] [client 172.17.0.1:54802]     connection = cx_Oracle.connect("test", "1234", "127.0.0.1:1521/XE")
[wsgi:error] [pid 1116] [client 172.17.0.1:54802] cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

I search for ORA-01804 error, and someone said it occurred by environment variable.

But I already set environment variable.

```
sh-4.2# export
export HOME="/root"
export HOSTNAME="651d1db71265"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib:"
export OLDPWD="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib"
export ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe"
export ORACLE_SID="XE"
export PATH="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
export PWD="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib"
export SHLVL="1"
export TERM="xterm"
export container="docker"
```

I set ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_SID.

in LD_LIBRARY_PATH,

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib
                                   |-- facility.lis
                                   |-- lclasses12.zip
                                   |-- libagtsh.so -> libagtsh.so.1.0
                                   |-- libagtsh.so.1.0
                                   |-- libcell11.so
                                   |-- libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
                                   |-- libclntsh.so.11.1
                                   |-- libclsra11.so
                                   |-- libcorejava.so
                                   |-- libdbcfg11.so
                                   |-- libemmas11.so
                                   |-- libhasgen11.so
                                   |-- libheteroxa11.so
                                   |-- libhgotrace11.so
                                   |-- libirc.a
                                   |-- libldapjclnt11.so
                                   |-- libnjni11.so
                                   |-- libnnz11.so
                                   |-- libnque11.so
                                   |-- libntcpaio11.so
                                   |-- libocci.so -> libocci.so.11.1
                                   |-- libocci.so.11.1
                                   |-- libocijdbc11.so
                                   |-- libocr11.so
                                   |-- libocrb11.so
                                   |-- libocrutl11.so
                                   |-- libodm11.so
                                   |-- libodmd11.so
                                   |-- libons.so
                                   |-- libqsmashr.so
                                   |-- libskgxn2.so
                                   |-- libskgxns.so
                                   |-- libskgxp11.so
                                   |-- libsqlplus.so
                                   |-- libsqora.so.11.1
                                   |-- libuini11.so
                                   |-- libwwg.a
                                   |-- libxdb.so
                                   `-- sysliblist1
```

libclntsh.so and libocci.so is in lib/, and set mode to 777.

but error is not fix.

And timezone is same.

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
---------
SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
02-NOV-20
02-NOV-20 11.44.08.355988 AM +00:00

sh-4.2# date
Mon Nov  2 11:44:17 UTC 2020
```

My python version is 3.6, and oracle is 11g Express Edition 64bit, Apache is 2.4.6.

What is the problem?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:1521/XE Is your container running in host-mode?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:1521/XE  is oracle connection information for python code. apache port is 80  for external connect

Comment: This will only work if docker container is running in host mode. Remember container(localhost) != host(localhost) in bridge mode

Comment: Assuming your DB is not in your container, you might find it easier to install Oracle Instant Client in the container, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1 and various examples at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers

Comment: Oracle 11.2 was released in 2009.  Why not at least use Oracle XE 18c https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html ?

Comment: My DB is in container, flask and apache  in container too.